# Styled Component only pass some value to custom component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

Hi I'm trying to configure the colour of a button base on it's button type which will be put in a modal. In this case, either "Success" or "Danger":

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

const ButtonStyled = styled.button`
    background-color: ${(props) =>
        props.btnType === "Success" ? "green" : "red"};
    border: none;
    color: white;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    font: Regular 400;
    padding: 0.5rem 0;
    margin: 0.5rem 1rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
`;

const Button = (props) => {
    console.log(props.btnType);
    return (
        <ButtonStyled btnType={props.btnType} onClick={props.clicked}>
            {props.children}
        </ButtonStyled>
    );
};

export default Button;
```

Here's where I called the button:

```
import React from "react";
import Button from "../../UI/Button/Button";

const OrderSummary = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Button btnType="Danger" clicked={props.cancelPurchase}>
                Cancel
            </Button>
            <Button btnType="Success" clicked={props.continuePurchase}>
                Continue
            </Button>
        </div>
    );
};

export default OrderSummary;
```

Here is where the Order Summary being called:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Modal from "../../components/UI/Modal/Modal";
import OrderSummary from "../../components/Burger/OrderSummary/OrderSummary";

const INGREDIENT_PRICES = {
    salad: 0.5,
    cheese: 0.4,
    meat: 1.3,
    bacon: 0.7,
};

const BurgerBuilder = () => {
    const [ingredients, setIngredients] = useState({
        salad: 0,
        bacon: 0,
        cheese: 0,
        meat: 0,
    });

    const [totalPrice, setTotalPrice] = useState(4);

    const [purchasing, setPurchasing] = useState(false);

    const purchaseCancelHandler = () => {
        setPurchasing(false);
    };

    const purchaseContinueHandler = () => {
        alert("continue");
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <Modal show={purchasing} modalClosed={purchaseCancelHandler}>
                <OrderSummary
                    continuePurchase={purchaseContinueHandler}
                    cancelPurchase={purchaseCancelHandler}
                    ingredients={ingredients}
                    price={totalPrice.toFixed(2)}
                />
            </Modal>
        </div>
    );
};

export default BurgerBuilder;
```

Down here is the modal where the Button being applied

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import Backdrop from "../Backdrop/Backdrop";

const ModalWrapper = styled.div`
    box-shadow: 0 5px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    background: #fff;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: #000;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 500;
    border-radius: 10px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    padding: 16px;
    left: 15%;
    top: 30%;

    @media (min-width: 600px) {
        width: 500px;
        left: calc(50% - 250px);
    }
`;

const ModalContent = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    line-height: 1.8;
    color: #141414;
    p {
        margin-bottom: 1rem;
    }
    button {
        padding: 10px 24px;
        background: #141414;
        // color: #fff;
        border: none;
    }
`;

const Modal = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Backdrop show={props.show} clicked={props.modalClosed} />
            <ModalWrapper
                style={{
                    transform: props.show ? "translateY(0)" : "translateY(-100vh)",
                    opacity: props.show ? "1" : "0",
                }}
            >
                <ModalContent>{props.children}</ModalContent>
            </ModalWrapper>
        </div>
        // <ModalStyled>{props.children}</ModalStyled>
    );
};

export default Modal;
```

As I did some testing, the values in the styled component Modal Content which state the button in that content will be that. Hence it affected the value of the styled component Button Styled. However, if I removed the value of button in Modal Content, the value of the color in ButtonStyled won't be accepted. Does anyone happen to know why?

Comment: Do you have more details about the problem? I tried your code in a Codesandbox and it works ok for me

Comment: Oh sorry, I found out the problem. It was because I wrapped it with in a Modal wrapper hence it is influenced by it. My modal content wrapper has these values:

const ModalContent = styled.div `
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 line-height: 1.8;
 color: #141414;
 p {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
 }
 button {
  padding: 10px 24px;
  background: #141414;
  // color: #fff;
  border: none;
 }
`;

Comment: However, shouldn't the Button component put in the modal out value the button inside the Modal content wrapper?

Comment: Let me update the question

Comment: So have you resolved this or is there still some issue? I don't see where you render a button in your modal. Please include all relevant code and how it is used so that one may be able to reproduce the issue. Is there a reason your modal content wrapper component is setting styles for `p` and `button` elements?

Comment: @DrewReese Hi, I still got the error. I just updated and include all the relevant code to the problem

Comment: Is the "error" the fact that you are overriding the button background color in the modal?

Comment: Yes. Even if I deleted the button from the Modal Content, the background color and the font still won't work @DrewReese

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The button style defined in the `ModalContent` is overriding the button style you've defined in your `Button` component.

```
button {
    padding: 10px 24px;
    background: #141414; // <-- overrides button background color
    border: none;
}
```

With CSS the most specific selector will be the one that sets the style and I suspect the `ModalContent` styled component's computed style results with a more specific selector for `button` elements than the one from `ButtonStyled`.

What you can do is bump the selector specificity of the `ButtonStyled` background color.

[Pseudoelements, pseudoselectors, and nesting](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#pseudoelements-pseudoselectors-and-nesting), the last section.

> Finally, the ampersand can be used to increase the specificity of
> rules on the component; this can be useful if you are dealing with a
> mixed styled-components and vanilla CSS environment where there might
> be conflicting styles

```
const ButtonStyled = styled.button`
  && {
    background-color: ${(props) =>
      props.btnType === "Success" ? "green" : "red"};
  }
  border: none;
  color: white;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font: Regular 400;
  padding: 0.5rem 0;
  margin: 0.5rem 1rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
`;
```

[image: Edit styled-component-only-pass-some-value-to-custom-component]